# Can't understand a simple Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain to me step by step what this function means?

```
select :: (a->a->Bool) -> a -> a -> a
```

Comment: That is a function signature, not a function.

Comment: What you have is not a function, it is a function *signature*. It tells you what types the function expects and returns. One can make an educated guess considering the types and the name, but it won't be more than that - a guess.

Answer (score 8):

As the comments pointed out, this is not a function definition, but just a type signature.  It says, for any type `a` which you are free to choose, this function expects:

- A function that takes two values of type `a` and gives a `Bool`
- Two values of type `a`

and it returns another value of type `a`.  So for example, we could call:

```
select (<) 1 2
```

where `a` is `Int`, since `(<)` is a function that takes two `Int`s and returns a `Bool`.  We could *not* call:

```
select isPrefixOf 1 2
```

because `isPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` -- i.e. it takes two lists (provided that the element type supports `Eq`uality), but numbers are not lists.

Signatures can tell us quite a lot, however, due to *parametericity* (aka *free theorems*).  The details are quite techincal, but we can intuit that `select` must return one of its two arguments, because it has no other way to construct values of type `a` about which it knows nothing  (and this can be proven).

But beyond that we can't really tell. Often you can tell almost certainly what a function does by its signature.  But as I explored this signature, I found that there were actually quite a few functions it could be, from the most obvious:

```
select f x y = if f x y then x else y
```

to some rather exotic

```
select f x y = if f x x && f y y then x else y
```

And the name `select` doesn't help much -- it seems to tell us that it will return one of the two arguments, but the signature already told us that.

Comment: Just for fun: in `select f x y`, there are four ways to call `f`, and for each of the 2^4=16 possible results from these four calls there are two choices of which value to return, so up to `undefined` shenanigans there are 2^16 = 65536 extensionally distinct implementations of this function.